# can i force jquerymobile to load pages via ajax (not external)?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

There are several ways to force an external load (data-ajax="false", rel="external"), but what if I have an external link that will serve me a jquery mobile page and I want it to load via ajax with transitions (without the page reloading)? Anyone have a straightforward solution?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm building a PhoneGap IOS app and the index.html file is no longer on the same path as the pages that are being fetched.

Thanks

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to have all the pages pre-created in the index.html code then call the content via ajax with pagebeforeshow... but this would involve completely re-writing the web application.

Comment: $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

Answer (score 0):

You can use framework such as jQTouch or jQuery Mobile. These frameworks have built in functions which can help you in call cross domain AJAX calls with in the application it self.

For example:

```
$.get("test.php", 
  { name: "micky", time: "2pm" }, 
  function(data){ 
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data); 
  } 
);
```

See demo here: http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/ but make sure to use web kit enabled browsers such as Chrome/Safari.